# Cannot run public class in one .java from another

Tags: java

I have created a basic program that takes whatever is input into two textfields and exports them to a file. I would now like to encrypt that file, and alredy have the encryptor. The problem is that I cannot call it. Here is my code for the encryptor:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.*;

import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.CipherInputStream;
import javax.crypto.CipherOutputStream;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;

public class FileEncryptor {

private String algo;
private File file;

public FileEncryptor(String algo,String path) {
this.algo=algo; //setting algo
this.file=new File(path); //settong file
}

 public void encrypt() throws Exception{
    //opening streams
     FileInputStream fis =new FileInputStream(file);
     file=new File(file.getAbsolutePath());
     FileOutputStream fos =new FileOutputStream(file);
     //generating key
     byte k[] = "HignDlPs".getBytes();   
     SecretKeySpec key = new SecretKeySpec(k,algo.split("/")[0]);  
     //creating and initialising cipher and cipher streams
     Cipher encrypt =  Cipher.getInstance(algo);  
     encrypt.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);  
     CipherOutputStream cout=new CipherOutputStream(fos, encrypt);

     byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
     int read;
     while((read=fis.read(buf))!=-1)  //reading data
         cout.write(buf,0,read);  //writing encrypted data
     //closing streams
     fis.close();
     cout.flush();
     cout.close();
 }

 public static void main (String[] args)throws Exception {
     new FileEncryptor("DES/ECB/PKCS5Padding","C:\\Users\\*******\\Desktop\\newtext").encrypt();//encrypts the current file.
  }
}
```

Here is the section of my file creator that is failing to call this:

```
FileWriter fWriter = null;
BufferedWriter writer = null;
try{
fWriter = new FileWriter("C:\\Users\\*******\\Desktop\\newtext");
writer = new BufferedWriter(fWriter);
writer.write(Data);
writer.close();
f.dispose();
FileEncryptor encr = new FileEncryptor(); //problem lies here.
encr.encrypt //public void that does the encryption.
new complete(); //different .java that is working fine.
```

Ok, I think I have it sussed. Thank you to all those who contributed.

Comment: I never imagined Dios (Spanish word for *God*) having programming problems =\

Comment: And the problem is...?

Comment: Never knew that. You learn something new everyday. But DIOS just stands for DarkInfernOfSouls.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Can Dios create an [esoteric programming language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Esoteric_programming_language) so difficult that even he can't write a "Hello, World" program in it?

Comment: @yshavit ask Dios about it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't pass anything into your constructor when using the `new` operator in your file creator:

```
FileEncryptor encr = new FileEncryptor(); //problem lies here.
```

However, you did when testing it in `main` in `FileEncryptor`:

```
new FileEncryptor("DES/ECB/PKCS5Padding","C:\\Users\\*******\\Desktop\\newtext").encrypt();//encrypts the current file.
```

Pass appropriate parameters.

Comment: Thank you, but how would I fix this, considering that I am still very new, and very bad at this.

Comment: Do you know what your encryption method and your encrypted file name are supposed to be? Use those.

Answer (score 1):

When you try to create your new FileEncryptor object, you have to use one of the constructors you implemented in the FileEncryptor.java file. Like this:

```
String anAlgo = "something";
String aPath = "something"'
FileEncryptor encr = new FileEncryptor(anAlgo, aPath);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Not sure why you have a main method in your FileEncryptor.java file. If you want `"DES/ECB/PKCS5Padding","C:\\Users\\*******\\Desktop\\newtext"` as your algorithm and your pathfile, then this is what your "something"s will be.

I think you should delete the main method in the first file and simply use that as your code in the 2nd file.

Answer (score 0):

There is only one constructor in this class which takes 2 arguments. This means that the object creation mechanism requires 2 arguments. If you need to create an object without these arguments, you can also provide a no argument constructor in addition to the 2 argument constructor like `public FileEncryptor(){//Default Constructor}` but then it would not make any sense since algo and path are required to perform encryption

Answer (score 0):

Your `public FileEncryptor(String algo,String path)` have constructor with two parameter. The compiler automatically provides a no-argument, default constructor for any class which doesn't have constructors. But as soon as you declare one, you won't be able call the empty constructor using `new FileEncryptor();` unless you specify it in the class context:

```
public class FileEncryptor {

   private String algo;
   private File file;

   public FileEncryptor(String algo,String path) {
      this.algo=algo; //setting algo
      this.file=new File(path); //settong file
   }

   public FileEncryptor()
   {
        // your code here
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the arguments for the Constructor of your FileEncryptor class.

This is your Constructor.

```
public FileEncryptor(String algo,String path) {
    this.algo=algo; //setting algo
    this.file=new File(path); //settong file
}
```

But you are creating an object like this.

```
FileEncryptor encr = new FileEncryptor(); //problem lies here.
```

You need to pass it the encryption algorithm name which you want to use and the path for the file which you want to encrypt.

The Cipher class gets an instance of the algorithm which you want to use for encryption.

```
Cipher encrypt =  Cipher.getInstance(algo);
```

Go through the documentation of Cipher class to see what types are supported. Here is the link.
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/crypto/Cipher.html#getInstance%28java.lang.String%29